# Exporting multiple WCS layers to GeoTIFFs to use them in rastercalculator

Tags: qgis, export, batch, wcs

I would like to know if anyone could tell me in what way I can export multiple WCS files to GeoTIFFS in QGIS. I use WCS files, but these cannot be used in the raster calculator. I first need to export them and save them as GeoTIFFS for example, but since I have over 30 layers I would like to know if there is a quick way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you use WCS files, which format do you mean?  Does the WCS support GeoTIFF as an export/output format?

Comment: WCS can return Tiff using &FORMAT=GEOTIFF_INT16 (if the server is set up to do that)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I lost my account for StackExchange.... the company delivered the WCS files in a GeoTIFF... thank you for the help though